# Laravel 'whereIn' every element in array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to filter the data with array, but return null if one of element in array is false.

for example my existing cars color is `['black', 'white', 'red']`

I already try with `whereIn` but in the docs say  `given containing value within the given array` thats why it's still return the data.

In my controller:

```
// the request param is /cars?color=black,white,yellow
$cars = Car::latest()->filter(request(['color', ...etc]))->get();
// $cars should empty

// the request param is /cars?color=black,white,red
$cars = Car::latest()->filter(request(['color', ...etc]))->get();
// $cars shouldn't empty
```

In my model:

```
public function colors() {
    return $this->hasMany(Color::class);
}

public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters) {
    $query->when($filters['color'] ?? false, function ($query, $colors) {
        $colors = explode(',', $color);
        $query->whereHas('colors', function ($q) use ($color) {
            $q->whereIn('color_name', $colors);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: please update  your code also so that we can help ;)

Comment: What have you tried? [edit] and post your code

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `where` condition for each selected colour:

```php
$cars = Car::whereHas('colors', function($q) use ($filter) {
    foreach ($filter as $color) {
        $q->where('color_name', $color);
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks right.

Comment: thanks for answer it, but it works when the filter array has 1 element, if more than element doesn't work

Comment: @TutiHerwiyati Because? What is the expected behaviour if there are no colours filtered? Seems like then you'd just get all cars that have at least one colour?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the function `whereIn` [Documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-wherein)

```
$filter = ['black', 'white', 'yellow'];
$cars = Car::whereIn('color_name', $filter)->get();
```